# Open API 3.0 parameter dependencies: required parameters if type is "one of" (with shared parameters)

Tags: openapi

I'm creating an `openapi.json` (version 3.0.3) schema and I'm modelling a post request. The body can look like this:

```
{
  type: "A",
  aParam: "string",
  sharedParam1: "string",
  sharedParam2: "integer",
  sharedParam3: "string"
}
```

where `type` is one of `A` or `B`. If the type is `A`, the parameter `aParam` is required if the type is `B` `aParam` must be left out. Basically, the other way the request can look is:

```
{
  type: "B",
  sharedParam1: "string",
  sharedParam2: "integer",
  sharedParam3: "string"
}
```

How can I model this?

Here is what I tried:

```
{
  "requestBody": {
    "content": {
      "application/json": {
        "schema": {
          "oneOf": [
            {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "type": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "enum": ["A"]
                },
                "aParam": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "sharedParam1": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "sharedParam2": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "sharedParam3": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "type": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "enum": ["B"]
                },
                "sharedParam1": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "sharedParam2": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "sharedParam3": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Basically, I "overloaded" the request body by using `oneOf` but that has a lot of duplication.

Answer (score 1):

You may extract the shared properties to a base schema. It won't make the definition much less verbose but at least will remove duplicated properties definitions making them more maintainable:

```
  "components": {
    "schemas": {
      "baseRequestBody": {
        "type": "object",
        "required": [
          "type",
          "sharedParam1",
          "sharedParam2",
          "sharedParam3"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "type": {
            "type": "string",
            "enum": [
              "A",
              "B"
            ]
          },
          "sharedParam1": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "sharedParam2": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "sharedParam3": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      },
      "requestBodyA": {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/baseRequestBody"
          },
          {
            "type": "object",
            "required": [
              "aParam"
            ],
            "properties": {
              "aParam": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "requestBodyB": {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/baseRequestBody"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

Additionally, you might want to use [Discriminator](https://swagger.io/specification/#discriminator-object) which can be used by some tools like code generators:

```
"requestBody": {
  "content": {
    "application/json": {
      "schema": {
        "oneOf": [
          {
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/requestBodyA"
          },
          {
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/requestBodyB"
          }
        ],
        "discriminator": {
          "propertyName": "type",
          "mapping": {
            "A": "#/components/schemas/requestBodyA",
            "B": "#/components/schemas/requestBodyB"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```